# What is the probability $P[k]$ of a run of length $k$ for rolling a die until a duplicate number appears?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, self-learning

**Book problem:** What is the probability $P[k]$ of a run of length $k$ for rolling a die until a duplicate number appears?

**My answer:**  $P[k] = 1 - 1(\frac{5}{6})(\frac{4}{6})\cdots(\frac{7-k}{6})$ for $k$ between $1$ and $6$; $P[k] = 1$ otherwise.

**Book answer:**  $1 - 1(1 - \frac{1}{6})(1 - \frac{2}{6})\cdots(1 - \frac{k}{6})$.

**Question:** Is there a typo in their answer?  When $k = 1$ I'd expect a probability of $0$, for example.

My own reasoning went as follows.

For a run of length $3$, so $k = 3$, to get no duplicates the probability would be $\frac{6\cdot 5\cdot 4}{6^3}$ so that to get at least one pair of duplicates we'd take the complement to get the answer.

**Book:** "Methods of Mathematics" by Hamming

Comment: I suspect the issue may be one of words rather than mathematics.  Are you looking for the probability the first duplicate appears at the $k+1$th roll (or perhaps $k$th roll), or that there has been at least one duplicate in the first $k+1$ rolls (or perhaps $k$ rolls).

Comment: On first reading I interpreted it as the first duplicate that appears on the kth roll, so for a run of length $k = 3$, for example, you could have rolled 1,4, 1 but not 4,4,2.  But after re-reading it, and thinking that I frequently misinterpret this author (his fault, not mine thank you), I read it as there has been at least one du[plicate in the first $k$ rolls.

Comment: for $k = 6$, book answer gives $P[6] = 1$, which is wrong?

Comment: @learner Yes.  It's possible to roll six different values.  Only when $k$ is 7 or higher, which represents 7 or more rolls, do we have to get any repetition.